# iPhone 6 and 6 plus screen sizes in pixels?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

What are `iPhone 6` and `6 plus` screen sizes in pixels ?

Need them for a application modification that is almost ready.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are upgrading your application to support `iPhone6` and `iPhone6+` and you do not wish for your application to scale on these devices you need to update your launch images to include:

iPhone Portrait:

- Retina HD 5.5 - 1242x2208px
- Retina HD 4.7 - 750x1334px

and or:

iPhone Landscape

- Retina HD 5.5 - 2208x1242px

Please note that although the screen size for the iPhone6+ is 1080x1920, it is using downscaled renders: https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/509438167280549888

[image]

Comment: Where do you assign the larger launch images? I only see "2x" and "Retina 4" items in the image assets.

Comment: If you are using asset catalogs - Find launch image - Open Attributes inspector - Add iOS 8 iPhone images. Available in xcode6

Comment: Not sure if you know - But you can also now set a xib / storyboard and therefore use auto layout. In Target > General > Launch Screen File. After testing this is only an iOS8 thing, so not viable until next year.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge is right. It is now possible to use an .xib for the launch screen. Has anyone found documentation about this?

Answer (score 3):

```
iphone 6 
750x1334 pixels

iphone 6 plus
1080x1920 pixels
```

Answer (score 1):

For 4.7-inch iPhone 6 features a 1334 x 750 display
For 5.5-inch iPhone 6 Plus features a 1920 x 1080 display

Answer (score 1):

iPhone 5s 640 by 1136 and aspect Ratio - 1.77
iPhone 6 750 by 1334 and aspect Ratio - 1.77
iPhone 6 plus 1080 by 1920 and aspect Ratio - 1.77

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 6 has a 4.7-inch LED back-lit display with a 1334 x 750 resolution - it's Apple's new "Retina HD" offering. That means you get a pixel density of 326ppi - the same as the iPhone 5S.
It also pales in comparison to the iPhone 6 Plus, with a full HD, 1920 x 1080 5.5-inch screen with a 401ppi display.

Answer (score 0):

**iPhone 6** display has `1134x750p` resolution while **iPhone 6** Plus has `1920x1080p`
While **iPhone 5** display has `1136x640`.

Source:

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/tech/tech-news/apple-iphone-6-iwatch/newsliveblog/42115338.cms?utm_source=facebook.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=TOI

[image]

Comment: Your resolution for iPhone 6 display is incorrect. That is the resolution for iPhone 5/5C/5S.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6 represents the biggest screen size boost in iPhone history. The larger size means more pixels for apps to work with. The iPhone 5 line had a `640 by 1136` screen resolution. The new phones boost that to `750 by 1334 and 1080 by 1920`, respectively.

[image]

For more details find on [Apple's official Site](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the ratio is the same as iPhone 5/ 5c 5s, so if your app runs on iPhone 5 / 5c 5s properly, it wouldn't be any problem to run on iPhone 6 / 6 Plus

Answer (score 0):

Resolutions of New iPhone 6 and 6+ are as follow

`iPhone6 - 750(W) x 1334(H) pixels, 4.7 inches`

`iPhone6 plus - 1080(W) x 1920(H) pixels, 5.5 inches`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus (as well as the 6s, 7, and 8 product lines) have a definite number of pixels that are listed many times among the answers. However, for other purposes (like standard web dev), it behaves as if its sizes are thus (presuming portrait orientation):

- 375px × 667px // iPhone 6, 6s, 7, and 8
- 414px × 736px // iPhone 6 Plus, 6s Plus, 7 Plus, and 8 Plus

These sizes are referred to in different places by the names "points" and "reference pixels". I prefer "reference pixels" only to avoid confusion with *printers’* points (72 or 72.27 per inch) generally (though not exclusively) used to measure typography.

For instance, when you are determining breakpoints, or layouts, it is the above numbers (reference pixels) that you will want to work in.

You can find more on the [Apple Developers’s site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html).